# Distinct & Group SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

I have a little bit complex MySQL query for me and i can't figure out how to write it without eating tons of memory. ( i don't really mind if it would )

I have the following table:

```
              TABLE: users(id,ip)
              ------------------------------------
              4BF1510 | 40.145.10.99 <-- SAME IP (A)
SAME ID   --> 510SD55 | 65.12.105.42 
SAME ID   --> 510SD55 | 45.184.15.10
              201505V | 40.145.10.99 <-- SAME IP (A)
              984AZ6C | 72.98.45.76
                      | 10.15.78.10  <-- SAME IP (B)
                      | 10.15.78.10  <-- SAME IP (B)
SAME ID   --> B1D56SX |  
SAME ID   --> B1D56SX |
```

I want a query that only fetchs 1 item per a unique id or ip, So:

```
4BF1510 | 40.145.10.99
510SD55 | 65.12.105.42
984AZ6C | 72.98.45.76
        | 10.15.78.10
B1D56SX |
```

The Most important things:

- If multiple entries have the same IP and same ID -> they'll be grouped
- If multiple entries have the same IP but different IDs -> they'll not be grouped
- If multiple entries have the same ID but different IPs -> they'll be grouped
- If multiple entries have the same IP but *empty* ID fields -> they'll be grouped
- If multiple entries have the same ID but *empty* IP fields -> they'll be grouped

Which means that the ID should have the first priority of trust, Because multiple users may use the same IP.

Any effective way to achieve that?

Tons of thanks.

Comment: What are the keys on this table? I'm confused as how can you have two distinct entries, both with no ID and the same IP.

Comment: I suspect your schema needs to be changed.  Perhaps ip should be in a different table that is linked by a primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are wanting to do can be accomplished using [group_contact](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Example

> SELECT id, **GROUP_CONCAT**(ip) as ips FROM *logs* group by id

edit: forgot group by

Comment: You are the most amazing person on the planet, you saved me ass years!