# Merging two different tables to form one but keeping related data

Tags: sql, ms-access, merge, ms-access-2010

Im a little new to Acess and am trying to understand how to merge tables.
My problem is basically this...
I have 2 reports that can be ran and exported to excel. I want to be able to take both reports, combine them, and import the combined result to a table.

In one report.. call it location detail... has the following fields:

```
ID        (PK, and autonumber)
Day       (Date call was done)
CallID    (Resets every day to 1, and increases by 1 for every new call)
Lat       (Lattitude of call)
Long      (Longitude of call)
Cost
```

In the other report.. call it location summary.. has the following fields:

```
ID              (PK, and autonumber)
Location
City
Lat             (Lattitude of call)
Long            (Longitude of call)
# of Occurences (Number of times there was a call at that location)
```

The problem is when you have a call in the same location, even though it was on two seperate days, it automatically groups it into the number of occurances. So I tried to run 2 seperate queries from the same range of dates, one matching lat, other matching long, it shows up with duplicates.. my guess is because the ones that do not have a matching lat (because it already used the field once, even though there were 4 occurences) are showing null value and are added to the query as a duplicate.

I want to add the City Column that matches the long/lat data, to the location details report, and then make that into a new table/ and then be able to run the same reports, and add them to the new table, but somehow ensure there arent any duplicates.

My biggest problem is there isnt any real primary key since the Call ID is Dependent on the Date.... I am not sure how to really accomplish this.

Any help would be much appreciated... I am Stumped.

EDIT:

The first Query is to join lattitudes:

```
SELECT 
  [Location Detail Report_142].Day, [Location Detail Report_142].[Call ID], 
  [Location Detail Report_142].Lat, [Location Detail Report_142].Long 
FROM [Location Detail Report_142] 
LEFT JOIN [Location Summary Report_14] 
    ON [Location Detail Report_142].Lat = [Location Summary Report_14].Lat;
```

The second one matches call id:

```
SELECT qryRelationshipToLat.Day, qryRelationshipToLat.[Call ID], 
  [Location Summary Report_14].City 
FROM [Location Summary Report_14] 
INNER JOIN qryRelationshipToLat 
  ON [Location Summary Report_14].Long = qryRelationshipToLat.Long     
ORDER BY qryRelationshipToLat.Day, [Location Summary Report_14].City;
```

I was thinking maybe it could be possible to make some sort of if-then statement stating that if call id shows duplicate THEN match Call ID... It has to match both, when the original Location Summary report is uploaded, it has 283 reccords, but it shows duplicate locations grouped into anouther field (#_of_Occurances), so the total amount of calls would be the total amount in the Location Detail report, witch in this case is 288. so when I run the first qry - 305 results, and the second qry turns the 305 to 337. So I end up with a lot of just duplicates I guess, or null value ones.

But the two reports both don't include Call ID or Call Numbers. The only information that they share is the LONG and LAT Coordinates. So I would have to match those first, then assign call ID, date, and city to the corresponding coordinates.

Comment: I suggest you post the SQL for both queries (get to the SQL by opening the query in SQL View instead of Design View).

Comment: Thanks for the response!    Right now I only have the data into two tables. Should I just run a query to put them into SQL Format?

Comment: You mentioned queries in the post.  Even though they didn't work, I think you should post them while explaining why they don't do what you want.  Answering your question probably requires a lot more precise detail than you have provided; viewing the SQL is hopefully a way to get to that information.

Comment: I was thinking maybe it could be possible to make some sort of if then statement stating that if call id shows duplicate THEN match Call ID... It has to match both, when the original Location Summary report is uploaded, it has 283 reccords, but it shows duplicate locations grouped into anouther field (#_of_Occurances), so the total amount of calls would be the total amount in the Location Detail report, witch in this case is 288. so when I run the first qry - 305 results, and the seccond qry turns the 305 to 337. So I end up with a lot of just duplicates I guess, or null value ones

Comment: But the two reports both don't include Call ID or Call Numbers. The only information that they share is the LONG and LAT Coordinates. So I would have to match those first, then assign call ID, date, and city to the corresponding coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* that you need to learn how to use a `GROUP BY` statement to aggregate your table.  These links may help:

- http://www.sqlteam.com/article/how-to-use-group-by-in-sql-server
- http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-group-by-clause.htm

It's possible also that your table designs have to be revised, and presumably your approach for adding to the call record as well.

I'm sorry to just throw some links at you, but I'm not quite up to analyzing what you have got  in order to construct a complete answer, and in any case I think you will have to tackle these areas of learning.

Comment: Thanks for the Quick Reply! I have been working 20 hour days the last few so I apologize for not being able to respond.  The Group Links you sent seem like they will defiantly do a lot to help me get the data to where it needs to be.  I just have to figure out how to take the data that is in the [# of Occurrences] field that is greater than one, to duplicate the entire row, change the value to 1 (or even remove entirely) and Create a new table with updated data, so I can have the same amount of rows on both tables. Then Group them.

Comment: I think instead you need to delete the table `location summary` and replace it with a query that handles the grouping.  For more precise instructions, we may need you to post sample data (perhaps as was done for http://stackoverflow.com/q/4379559/122139).

Comment: What is the best way to post sample data, is it better with a pic of the Database or is there a way to format a chart?

Comment: Put it this way, I believe that the way that I want to do it here is a little to complicated, and way over thought.  I think that I may have found a way to simplify what I am asking and what I am trying to accomplish.....    Basically this is what I have come up with that I would like to do....  I would like to Combine two tables. Both with different number of columns... IF [date] and [call ID] match, then combine data from both tables to form one table with alot more information. Can that be done with a Query? then converted into a table?